# how to solver n + 1 problem with nested on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 4 models. I have gem bullet installed. When I enter a proposal that has a lot of equipment, I get the N+1 problem alert.  It asks me to put includes(:equipment) in the proposal item. I do, but the N +1 message always appears.

**Proposal**

```
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :proposal_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :proposal_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

**Client**

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :clients
    has_many :proposals
```

**Proposal Item**

```
class ProposalItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :proposal
  belongs_to :equipment
```

**Equipment**

```
class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :proposal_items
```

I've tried putting it in the proposal controller:

```rb
def index
    @proposals = Proposal.includes(:job, :employee, :client, proposal_item: :equipment).
```

but that's for the index method. The n +1 alert appears when I enter the show method.

Does anyone know how I can solve it?

Comment: What does the message from bullet look like? What does your `show` action look like?

Comment: Hi!
the message from bullet:

GET /proposals/3
USE eager loading detected
  ProposalItem => [:equipment]
  Add to your query: .includes([:equipment])
Call stack

Method show:

 def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html

Comment: Are you facing the issue for show method?

Comment: no issues or errors on method

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to make one suggestion about your models, maybe you have it already, and just forgot to put it in your snippets, but:

```rb
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :proposal_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many : Equipment, through: :proposal_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :proposal_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

with this, you will be able to do the following:

```rb
 @proposals = Proposal.includes(:job, :employee, :client, :proposal_items)
```

Probably, it should solve the problem.

Comment: HI!

with all the changes, the message of n + 1 continues

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the issue is now gone in `index` method, but still present in `show` method, is that correct ?

If yes, then it's because a `Proposal` has many `ProposalItems` and for each of `ProposalItem` it will try to fetch the `Equipment`. To fix it by using eager load, you can do this in `show` method:

```
def show
  @proposal = Proposal.includes(proposal_items: [:equipment]).find_by(params[:id])
end
```